# Capistrano::NoMatchingServersError on deploy:update_code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I have a capistrano deploy script that works on my windows local machine but a coworker on a mac is hitting a deploy error.  It's actually just his laptop since it works on other macs as well, so I'm wondering if there is some capistrano cache that needs to be cleared?  The error is...

```
* Compressing /var/folders/kv/g4k3rk815sd14948vzf1lhg40000gn/T/20131203013325 to /var/folders/kv/g4k3rk815sd14948vzf1lhg40000gn/T/20131203013325.tar.gz
    executing locally: tar czf 20131203013325.tar.gz 20131203013325
    command finished in 114ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::NoMatchingServersError, `deploy:update_code' is only run for servers matching {:except=>{:no_release=>true}}, but no servers matched `deploy:update_code' is only run for servers matching {:except=>{:no_release=>true}}, but no servers matched
```

My deploy.rb (the important parts) are as follows...

```
set :application, "app"

task :prod do 
  role :app, "10.1.40.123"
  role :web, "10.1.40.123"
  role :db,  "10.1.40.123", :primary => true
  set :user, "root"
  set :password, "password"
  set :rails_env, "production"
  set :use_sudo, false
  load 'deploy/assets' # this line runs rake assets precompile
  set :os, 'ubuntu'
  default_environment["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = '/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1'
end 
set :repository, "ssh://gituser@example.com/opt/git/hub/app.git"
set :deploy_to, "/srv/www/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :keep_releases, 5

set :scm, "git"
set :branch, "master"

after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_shared', "deploy:migrate","deploy:restart"
```

He is able to deploy other apps using capistrano, we are using capistrano 2.

Comment: What Capistrano gem and ruby version are you using, he using, and other macs using?

Comment: capistrano 2.15.5 - rails 3.2.13 - ruby 1.9.3? not 100% sure regarding his ruby version.

Comment: for sure its > ruby 1.8

Comment: we are all on the same capistrano, rails version, our team is mostly using ruby 1.9.x

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to deploy to multiple stages with a custom task instead of using [multistage extension](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension). This way when you are running `cap prod` you are not actually deploying, and when running `cap deploy` you are not setting the roles, which causes the error in question. So, the solution would be to rewrite your `deploy.rb` to something like the following:

```
set :stages, %w(prod staging)
set :default_stage, "staging"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :application, "app"
set :repository, "ssh://gituser@example.com/opt/git/hub/app.git"
set :deploy_to, "/srv/www/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :keep_releases, 5

set :scm, "git"
set :branch, "master"

after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_shared', "deploy:migrate","deploy:restart"
```

Then, in your `config/deploy/prod.rb` you should have your prod-related setup:

```
role :app, "10.1.40.123"
role :web, "10.1.40.123"
role :db,  "10.1.40.123", :primary => true
set :user, "root"
set :password, "password"
set :rails_env, "production"
set :use_sudo, false
load 'deploy/assets' # this line runs rake assets precompile
set :os, 'ubuntu'
default_environment["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = '/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1'
```

This way you'll be able to deploy to production with `cap prod deploy` (or with `cap deploy` too if you change `set :default_stage, "staging"` to `set :default_stage, "prod"`).

Comment: At the moment I just have one environment for this app, but I am running cap prod deploy.  I have the exact same code as in my question for another app (with the exception of git location and appname) and he is able to deploy, so I don't think it is the syntax of the code itself.  Could be wrong though, who knows, just a strange error overall.

Comment: What's the point of having `prod` task then? Try removing `task :prod do` and the corresponding `end` (leaving the code in-between in place), then `cap deploy` should work correctly.

Comment: Coworker hasn't responded yet so i don't know if this works but no point in letting a bounty go to waste so +50 for the effort! Thanks.